# How to prove $x^p\equiv x\mod p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have already proved that $(x+y)^p\equiv x^p+y^p\mod p$.

And if I take $y=1$, how do I prove the congruency $x^p\equiv x\mod p$? (I should use induction to $x$ but I dont know how to do that in this case)

Comment: Hint: Observe that every term in the expansion of $(x+y)^p$ except $x^p$ and $y^p$ contains a $p$ (or a power of $p$) multiplying it, so those terms are $0 \text{ mod } p$, try to formalize the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(x+1)^p\equiv x^p+1\equiv x+1\pmod p$$

Comment: That is not a proof by induction.

Comment: Fixed, I guess.

Comment: sorry, i meant induction to $x$, yes. But what are the induction steps here?

Comment: @Barry_Allen base case: $x = 0$.  Inductive step: suppose it holds for an integer $x$ between $0$ and $p$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If it holds for an x between 0 and p, i show what's written in ajotatxe's answer and im done?

Comment: Well ajotatxe's answer shows that it must also, then, hold for $x+1$.  So yes.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom and ajotatxe thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Initial case $x=0$
$$x^p\equiv 0^p \equiv 0 \mod p$$
Same goes for 1 if you want that to be the start case, now assume that $$x^p\equiv x \mod p$$
By your own theorem we have
$$(x+y)^p\equiv x^p+y^p \mod p$$
so for $x+1$ we get
$$(x+1)^p\equiv x^p+1^p \equiv x^p+1 \mod p$$
hence it must be true.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, $(x + 1)^p\equiv x^p + 1\mod p$

Then $((x + 1) + 1)^p\equiv (x + 1)^p + 1\equiv (x^p + 1) + 1\equiv x^p + 2\mod p$

And so on, so by induction $x^p\equiv x\mod p$

Answer (score -3):

Using Euler's Theorem, we have that  $x^p\equiv x\cdot x^{p-1} \equiv x\cdot x^{\phi(p)}\equiv x\cdot 1 \equiv x (mod p)$.